# What is the matter with my require statement to call phpmailer?

Tags: php, composer-php, phpmailer

The directory for my composer and phpmailer.

```
tree -L 3  /home/bwg
/home/bwg
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
└── vendor
    ├── autoload.php
    ├── composer
    │   ├── autoload_classmap.php
    │   ├── autoload_namespaces.php
    │   ├── autoload_psr4.php
    │   ├── autoload_real.php
    │   ├── autoload_static.php
    │   ├── ClassLoader.php
    │   ├── installed.json
    │   └── LICENSE
    └── phpmailer
        └── phpmailer
            ├── get_oauth_token.php
            ├── LICENSE
            ├── README.md
            ├── SECURITY.md
            ├── src
            │   ├── Exception.php
            │   ├── OAuth.php
            │   ├── PHPMailer.php
            │   ├── POP3.php
            │   └── SMTP.php
            └── VERSION
```

I want to send email from vps  with phpmailer,save the following code as `sendmail.php`(part of it,debug  part by part),write the code according to webpage here.
[HOW TO SEND YOUR FIRST EMAIL WITH PHPMAILER](https://alexwebdevelop.com/phpmailer-tutorial/)

```
<?php
ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
error_reporting( E_ALL );
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require '/home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php';
require '/home/bwg/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/bwg/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require '/home/bwg/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
?>
```

Type `http://vps_ip/sendmail.php` in my browser, come across the problem:

> Warning: require(/home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/sendmail.php on line 6
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/sendmail.php on line 6

```
ls  -al  /home/bwg/vendor
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 07:55 .
drwx------ 5 bwg    bwg    4096 Sep 23 11:10 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache  178 Sep 23 07:55 autoload.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 07:55 composer
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 07:55 phpmailer
```

What is the matter with my require statement?

Comment: The statement is OK (although is extremely unportable - you should use `__DIR__` to build your paths), the problem is in your webserver permissions - it does not have access to this file.

Comment: What rob006 said. You only need to require `autoload.php`; if you've set up your project with composer correctly, it will load whatever classes it needs dynamically, you don't need to load them explicitly.